# how to display a image in django template using for loop

Tags: python, html, django

I am trying to display a image in the django template

html file

```
{% for imge in q_i %}
<img src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}/{{ imge.0 }}" width="80" height="80" />
{% endfor %}
```

view.py

```
#...#
Q_I = []
for q in s_q:
    img = Images.objects.get(id=1)
    img_path=img.imgfile
    Q_I.append(img_path)
return render_to_response('1.html',{'q_i':Q_I},context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

But this code is not working.
Am i doing it wrong?
Thanks in advance

Comment: what does not working mean? ... what happens if you print `{{q_i}}`

Comment: nothing gets displayed

Comment: and when you print `{{q_i}}`? ... you have no `{%endfor%}` in your html ... maybe thats the problem?  is there any source if you view source? It doesnt work is not a helpful problem description.. you will need to do some more debugging

Comment: Are you sure this is the `view.py` code? You are not doing anything useful there. Also, if nothing gets printed for `{{q_i}}`, your `s_q` is `None` or `0`

Comment: Instead of the forloop, you can do `imgfile = Images.objects.get(id=1).imgfile; Q_I=[imgfile]*len(s_q)` and in the template,  `<img src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ imge }}" width="80" height="80" />` in the forloop

Answer (score 0):

Several things are wrong with this code.

Seems to me like `imge` doesn't have a meaningful `0` property, you're setting imge to be the path to the image, so `imge.0` is the first character of that path, not sure if that's what you want.  Also, be more specific about what's not working, what errors or output are you getting vs what you're expecting.

What/where is MEDIA_URL?

Why are you looping through s_q? Not really using it inside the loop...and you always get the same image (id=1)